# How to validate react router route params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use the function for `generatePath`. I get the error when not pass params which are required for the route.

```
const route = ':id/:id2'
generatePath(route, { id: 'id' }) 
Uncaught TypeError: Expected 'id2' to be defined
```

I am searching for a way how to validate route before use in `generatePath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternatively, you can try to use `matchPath` function from `react-router-dom`
if route parameters are valid `generatePath` function will generate the path else you get an error

you can console.log to check

also replace 'yourId' with actual value you want to use for the `id`

```
import {matchPath, generatePath} from 'react-router-dom';

`const route = ':id/:id2';`

 const params = {id: 'yourId'};

const isValidRoute = matchPath(route, params);

if (isValidRoute){



 const path = generatePath(route, params);



console.log('Generated path:', path);

}else {

   console.log('Invalid route:', params);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of validating before using `generatePath`, you can simply create a function that wraps `generatePath` and catch the error :

```
function safeGeneratePath() {

 const route = ':id/:id2'

 try {

   const path = generatePath(route, { id: 'id' }) 
   return path

 } catch(error){

   // do something here if it fails
   return null // for example

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When utilizing TypeScript, the `genratePath` parses URLs automatically and searches for variables in string, so you can avoid runtime validation.

For instance, when dealing with a `URL` pattern like `/foo/:id`, the function's second argument will require you to define `{ id: string | number | boolean }.`

```
import { generatePath } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const url = generatePath(
    '/foo/:id',
    { id: 123 } // OK
);


const url = generatePath(
    '/foo/:id',
    { } // Error
);
// Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: string | number | boolean; }'.
```